# How to exploit Unified Memory in OpenCL with CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR flag?

Tags: arm, opencl, mali, unified-memory

How can I use unified memory on an OpenCL device without copying data correctly?

OpenCL defined [CL_DEVICE_HOST_UNIFIED_MEMORY](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/sdk/3.0/docs/man/html/clGetDeviceInfo.html) as:

> Is CL_TRUE if the device and the host have a unified memory subsystem and is CL_FALSE otherwise.

The ARM Mali [docs](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101574/0400/Optimizing-OpenCL-for-Mali-GPUs/Optimizing-memory-allocation/About-memory-allocation?lang=en) suggests to use unified memory, the flag `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR` should be used while creating a buffer. The flag is described as:

> This is a hint to the driver indicating that the buffer is accessed on the host side. To use the buffer on the application processor side, you must map this buffer and write the data into it. This is the only method that does not involve copying data. If you must fill in an image that is processed by the GPU, this is the best way to avoid a copy.

However, there are no examples of how to use buffers created with the flag `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR`. The example I wrote does not seem to do it properly.

Consider the following code snippet to use such buffers:

```cpp
    // Create Buffers
    constexpr size_t n_bytes = sizeof(int) * SZ_ARR;
    cl::Buffer buffer_A(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR,
                        n_bytes);
    cl_int error{0};
    int* A = static_cast<int*>(
        queue.enqueueMapBuffer(buffer_A, CL_FALSE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, n_bytes,
                               nullptr, nullptr, &error));
    gpuErrchk(error);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SZ_ARR; ++i) {
        A[i] = i;
    }
    gpuErrchk(queue.enqueueUnmapMemObject(buffer_A, A));
    cl::Kernel add(program, "add_and_print");
    add.setArg(0, buffer_A);
    gpuErrchk(queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(add, cl::NullRange,
                                         cl::NDRange(SZ_ARR), cl::NullRange));
    queue.finish();
```

I am creating the buffer `buffer_A` to contain ten ints. I expect to write these ten ints after mapping them with  `enqueueMapBuffer` and then unmapping them with `enqueueUnmapMemObject`. The kernel `add_and_print` adds `1` to each array element and prints the resulting value. In particular, the kernel is:

```cpp
    const std::string kernel_code =
        "   void kernel add_and_print(global int* A) {"
        "       int i = get_global_id(0);"
        "       A[i] = A[i] + 1;"
        "       printf(\"%d\", A[i]);"
        "   }";
```

However, the program prints `1` for each array element.

How can I use a unified buffer properly?

For reference, the full program to reproduce the code is below:

```cpp
#include <CL/opencl.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#define gpuErrchk(ans) \
    { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cl_int code, const char* file, int line,
                      bool abort = true) {
    if (code != CL_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert, error code: %d %s %d\n", code, file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

constexpr size_t SZ_ARR = 10;

cl::Device getDevice() {
    std::vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
    gpuErrchk(cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms));
    cl::Platform default_platform = all_platforms[0];
    std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
    gpuErrchk(default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &all_devices));
    cl::Device default_device = all_devices[0];
    std::cout << "Using device: " << default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>()
              << "\n";
    return default_device;
}

cl::Program buildProgram(cl::Context& context, cl::Device& device) {
    const std::string kernel_code =
        "   void kernel add_and_print(global int* A) {"
        "       int i = get_global_id(0);"
        "       A[i] = A[i] + 1;"
        "       printf(\"%d\", A[i]);"
        "   }";
    cl::Program::Sources sources{{kernel_code.c_str(), kernel_code.length()}};

    cl::Program program(context, sources);
    if (program.build({device}) != CL_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "Error building: "
                  << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(device)
                  << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    return program;
}

int main() {
    // Prologue: Get device, context, and build program
    cl::Device default_device = getDevice();
    cl::Context context({default_device});
    cl::Program program = buildProgram(context, default_device);
    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, default_device);

    // Create Buffers
    constexpr size_t n_bytes = sizeof(int) * SZ_ARR;
    cl::Buffer buffer_A(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR,
                        n_bytes);
    cl_int error{0};
    int* A = static_cast<int*>(
        queue.enqueueMapBuffer(buffer_A, CL_FALSE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, n_bytes,
                               nullptr, nullptr, &error));
    gpuErrchk(error);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SZ_ARR; ++i) {
        A[i] = i;
    }
    gpuErrchk(queue.enqueueUnmapMemObject(buffer_A, A));
    cl::Kernel add(program, "add_and_print");
    add.setArg(0, buffer_A);
    gpuErrchk(queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(add, cl::NullRange,
                                         cl::NDRange(SZ_ARR), cl::NullRange));
    queue.finish();
}
```